# How to upgrade magento cloud 2.4.3-p1 to 2.4.3-p3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3, magento2.4.3.p1

can you please help me How to upgrade magento cloud 2.4.3-p1 to 2.4.3-p3 ?
I have tried below command but it's displaying the 2.4.3-beta1 version.

```
composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":">=2.4.3-p3 <2.4.5" --no-update
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading your Magento store with latest version, please follow the steps:

1: Run the below command:

```
composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":">=CURRENT_VERSION <NEXT_VERSION" --no-update
```

2: Update the project:

```
composer update
```

3: Add, commit, and push code changes.

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Upgrade"
git push origin <branch-name>
```

Both composer update and composer install commands consist of the files from the base package (magento/magento2-base and magento/magento2-ee-base. So it's necessary to make sure it doesn't marshal your files.

4: Wait for deployment to complete.

5: Verify the upgrade in your Integration, Staging, or Production environment by using SSH to log in and check the version.

```
php bin/magento --version
```

6: Check if your composer.json is updated with current version.

7: Also update dependencies:

```
composer update magento/magento-cloud-metapackage --update-with-dependencies
```

Thanks

Comment: Hello Jyotishina
I have already performed stpe1 and step2 
But after the deployment complete and i have checked the magento version and it's displaying the 2.4.4-beta1 version.

Comment: Hi @KarangarMeghnathi did you check your composer.json it's showing the updated version or not? and also try composer update magento/magento-cloud-metapackage --update-with-dependencies to update all dependencies. Also, make sure the composer.json file is readable and writeable with the correct permissions.

Comment: yes already update

Comment: Could you share composer json version or file?

Comment: I have updated the ECE tools and working fine. 
Thanks